# I need to know the number of serialized lists in the file. help me please

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

I need to know the number of serialized lists in the file.

```
n = 0
f = open('comics', 'rb')
while pickle.load(f):
    n+=1
```

Comment: sorry about code n = 0 // f = open('comics', 'rb') // while pickle.load(f): n+=1

Comment: I assume you are getting EOFError. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to catch "EOFError" since you will run out of pickled lists. It's also better to use with statement for opening files since you don't have to worry about closing the open files.

```
n = 0
with open('comics', 'rb') as f:
    while True:
        try:
            pickle.load(f):
            n+=1
        except EOFError:
            break
```

Comment: Tim I did not even hope that someone would find a solution. I was allowed to write my course project in python, when all my classmates write in c ++. None of the teachers could not help me, because they are not familiar with python. I am very grateful for your help!

I hope you can read it. My English is bad, but I wanted to thank you at least a word.

Comment: @АлексейКуракин Glad to help. Good luck!